# What's the difference between GroovyShell and GroovyScriptEngine?

Tags: groovy

Specifically http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html and http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html. In what situations would you use one over another?

Comment: have a look at the docs: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_groovyscriptengine

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for the ref. You can add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dl**: the script engine is for a groovy eco system; the shell for running scripts

The docs explain that in the section [Groovy integration mechanisms](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_groovy_integration_mechanisms).

From [GroovyScriptEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_groovyscriptengine)

> The `groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine` class provides a flexible foundation for applications which rely on script reloading and script dependencies. While `GroovyShell` focuses on standalone `Script`'s and `GroovyClassLoader` handles dynamic compilation and loading of any Groovy class, the `GroovyScriptEngine` will add a layer on top of `GroovyClassLoader` to handle both script dependencies and reloading.

further down the text is an example where a running script engine reloads classes automatically and also dependencies.